# SharePoint 2016 Licensing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, migration, 2016, licensing

We are planning to migrate and upgrade to SharePoint 2016, currently we have a SharePoint Enterprise 2013 server farm and we want to know if there's any special matter about licensing for new servers if we decide to do a migration.

**Our current licensed infrastructure is:**

- 1 WFE Server
- 1 Application Server (for Search)
- 1 Application Server (for SRSS and other intrinsec SP services)
- 1 Workflow Server
- 1 Office Apps Server
- 1 SQL 2014 Database Server

If you need more info, just let me know.

Comment: what you want to ask, is not clear? do you have license for the SharePoint and SQL?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE we actually have everything licensed, I want to know, as stated in my question if there's any special matter if we decide to do a  migration.

Comment: You can watch the video on SharePoint Licensing for all the question at > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZF-b-U5LaY&t=1s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your licensing covered all the Servers and Cals for every user, you are fine. You need Entreprise Cal if you are using enterprise features. BTW there is no change from the 2013.

> SharePoint Server 2016 is required for each running instance of the
>   software, and CALs are required for each person or device accessing a
>   SharePoint Server.

https://products.office.com/en-us/SharePoint/sharepoint-licensing-overview

OOS licensing is Seprate

> Customers with a Volume Licensing account can download OOS from the
>   Volume License Servicing Center at no cost and will have view-only
>   functionality, which includes PowerPoint sharing in Skype for
>   Business. Customers that require document creation, edit and save
>   functionality in OOS will need to have an on-premises Office suite
>   license with Software Assurance or an Office 365 ProPlus subscription.

https://blogs.office.com/2016/05/04/office-online-server-now-available/

Comment: Great info, thanks a lot! I didn't knew about OOS...